# Logout when closing window in Angular 4

Tags: angular, http, synchronous

I have an Angular 4 applicaton and I want to call the logout function when the user close the page (window or tab of the browser).

This is my logout function :

```
    let currentUser: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Basic ' +  btoa(currentUser.login + ":" + currentUser.password),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, authorization'
    });

    let opts = new RequestOptions();
    opts.headers = headers;


   return this.http.get(this.route + 'UserLogout', opts).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

And in my app.component.ts, I have :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    this.authenticationService.logoutOnClose().subscribe(res=> {
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    });

}
```

But the window is close and the request is never done. I think I need to do the request synchronously but I don't know how to do it.

Do you have an idea ?

**EDIT**
I tried with jQuery :

```
 ngOnDestroy(){
    let currentUser: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    $.ajax({ url: 'myURL',
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authority", 'Basic ' +  btoa(currentUser.login + ":" + currentUser.password));
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, authorization');
        },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
        alert('test');
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }, async: false });
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing credentials in localstorage, just store them in a global variable which will be automatically destroyed on tab close and the next time user opens tab he will not have `login` and `password` for `Authorization` headers, so he will be forced to login again by ur backend

Comment: Yes, but I need to call the function to close the session in backend. If I logout in the angular app, I need to close the session in backend and not just block the angular application.

Comment: what are you using in backend ?

Comment: I don't want to modify the backend.

Comment: What i am trying to understand is that are you using session cookies or not ? Because if you do use session cookies without expiration time than user will be automatically logged out on closing window.

Comment: No, the session will never close if I don't call the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158606/discussion-between-dhyey-and-adrien).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found how to do it. So, I would prefer avoid jQuery with Angular but like Sriram Jayaraman I didn't find anything else to fix my problem. But the functions `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` and `@HostListener('window:onunload')` are not working.

So, in the ngOnInit of my app.component.ts, I added an event listener for `beforeunload` to the window and if the user is connected I call a function which make an ajax call.

This is my code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    let context = this;
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        let currentUser : User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if(currentUser){
            context.logoutOnClose();
        }
    });
}

logoutOnClose(){
    let currentUser: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    $.ajax({ url: 'myURL',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' +  btoa(currentUser.login + ":" + currentUser.password));
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-origin, content-type, authorization');
    },
    type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    },
    async: false });
}
```

Comment: Will take my word back.. using @HostListener worked for me too however, you should be using "window:beforeunload" i was using "window:onbeforeunload" which was wrong and was the missing piece.

Comment: When the synchronous requests go away, this solution will no longer work
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs

Comment: It calls the function when I close the browser but when i refresh the page it calls function too.

Comment: mine works good with refresh as well since i replaced ```localStorage``` with ```sessionStorage```

Comment: Even i user clicks cancel and not on "LEAVE" button the user is still logged out which might not be the expected behavior

Answer (score 4):

You can store your user and credentials in `sessionStorage` rather than `localStorage`. `sessionStorage` is removed whenever you close tab/browser, `localStorage` don't !

Comment: Thanks, I will change that but it doesn't fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

If it is for localstorage, I have written the following code in app.component.ts. It worked for me.

```
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) windowBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
localStorage.clear();}
```

It wont give any alert or confirm boxes in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you disconnect your user on leaving is up to you. But if you want to do that, you have to adapt your code and logic to the framework, and not the other way around.

This means that you have to rewrite the user session when the user logs in again, or have a job that deletes unused sessions.

But in both ways, all you have to do is delete your localStorage/SessionStorage. If you do this, this will be transparent to the user, it's just how you manage it on your server that will change (but the user will have no idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any code that has to be executed to the `OnDestroy` function in your `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.authenticationService.logoutOnClose().subscribe(res=> {
            localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    });
}
```

However I'm not sure how this will handle the asynchronous call.. but it's worth trying.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if I just do an alert in the `ngOnDestroy`, the alert is never displayed

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to implement the following:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
windowBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    event.returnValue = "any value here";
}
```

If `event.returnValue` contains any value, the browser will show one of these pop-ups:

[image]

or

[image]

Then to check whether the user selected <kbd>Reload</kbd> or <kbd>Leave</kbd>, the following event will hit:

```
@HostListener('window:unload')
windowOnUnload() {
    //User pressed Reload/Leave.
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
}
```

If you clear the user in `window:beforeunload` and the user selects <kbd>Cancel</kbd> in the browser popup, then you would have logged out the user then it causes problems.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is that, make the API call synchronous using `jQuery` for this portion and make it synchronous as required. It is easy and does the job well.

Comment: For example in your component:

`declare var $: any;`

`$.ajax({
        url: 'yourUrl',
        success: function (result) {

        },
        async: false
    });`

Comment: Please, avoid using jQuery in Angular apps!

Comment: Angular have `http` and `subscribe()`, why `jQuery`?

Comment: I had done some research when I was having the same problem, and there is no way that I found digging, to make a subscription or observable synchronous. The best solution that I eventually landed was making a jQuery call even though I did not like it.

Comment: ngOnDestroy will not work because the page unloads before the component is destroyed. Call it in `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')`. Additionally you can call it in `@HostListener('window:onunload')` too, for some browsers the later worked when the former didn't work.

Comment: I tried this too, and it doesn't work... I put the same code in `@HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
    beforeUnloadHander(event) { ... }` and it doesn't work

Comment: Your alert may not work as the response might be too slow for the browser. Check if your server received any call

Comment: The server receive the `Request Method:OPTIONS` with status 200 OK but not the GET

Comment: Well to be frank, I do not know how that works, try removing the beforeSend  method from the request call. Maybe that might work

Comment: It's the same again