# How to execute some code before closing browser?

Tags: angular

I want to execute localStorage.clear() before I close my browser. I have tried this:

```
export class AppComponent {

    @HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
        clearLocalStorage(event){
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

But no results. Any ideas ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015284/clear-local-storage-when-the-browser-closes-in-angular It's "window:beforeunload" not "window:ONbeforeunload"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we detect when user closes browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `AppComponent` implements `OnDestroy` interface.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy{

    ngOnDestroy() {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```