# While refreshing application on browser application is getting logout

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angular6, dom-events

While refreshing browser application is getting logout. Before when closing browser then application was not getting logout for that used

```
@HostListener('window:unload', [])

onWindowunload() {
  this.logout();
}

//code for getting logout while closing browser
//for refresh
```

Above code it is getting logout when we are closing the browser but also getting logout when we are refreshing the browser

```
@HostListener('window:reload', [])
onWindowreload() {
}
```

**Expected result:** when we close the browser then it should get logout but when we refresh the browser the it should not get logout.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Can You please specify how you are implementing this logout/login functionality. One thing I know is you can use SessionStorage or LocalStorage for storing use credential.
If You are using any of these then please check the difference between the two. 
[Difference between local and session storage.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

If you are using any other api for login/logout functionality then please specify.

Also check when you are calling the logout function. On refresh of the page?? You question is not clear.

Comment: we are using angular CookieServices for storing credential and we are not using any other api call we had created logout() we are calling that for getting logout.

Comment: Actually my problem is that we are not able to do seperate action when we are closing browser it should get logout but when we are refreshing browser it should not get logout. We are using Angular6 (Typescript) in our project. Wish i am clear with my problem now

Comment: check out this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199361/logout-when-closing-window-in-angular-4