# How can I make my application logout when the browser is closed?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on a project with Angular7 typescript and a nodejs backend. I want the application to log out the user when they close the browser. How can I achieve this using typescript?

I am using the function below to do my normal signout and it works. How can I call it when the browser closes?

```
logout(): void {
    this.cookieService.delete('jwt_token', '/');
    this.cookieService.delete('my_token', '/');
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.clockSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout when closing window in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199361/logout-when-closing-window-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Component({ 
  ...
)}
class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  logout() {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your token, user and credentials in `sessionStorage` rather than `localStorage`. `sessionStorage` is removed whenever you close tab/browser, `localStorage` don't!