# How to call a nodejs logout api when close the browser tab?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, oauth

I have some trouble in login logout athentication:-

My required logic:-

When user closes a web browser i need a intimation from client to server as customer logged out.

Using angular and node for the application. Tried using Unload, beforeUnload, Socket.io functions. But i can't get the clear way.

Comment: what kind of authorisation you are using? if you are storing a token on localstorage simply delete the `localstorage` so automatically user is logout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logout when closing window in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199361/logout-when-closing-window-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i found a solution using Socket.io , Write the emit function in app module, When you close the browser tab directly it will emit a function to backend. then you can update a document user got logged out.